# React: Why on .map an array doesn't show list of items?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm trying to show list of items that i get from an API in the backend. However, when I try to map the array, then it doesn't show any item. What am I doing wrong? Anyone could help please?

I tried to console log and I can see list of items being fetched correctly. The h2 tag also displays. but not the .map results.

This is the code:

```
interface Props {
  products: Product[] | [];
}

const ProductsList = ({ products }: Props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getProducts();
    console.log('fetched data', getProducts());
  }, []);

  return (
    <RootContainer>
      <h2>test</h2>
      {products &&
        products.map((product) => {
          return <ProductItem key={product.id} product={product} />;
        })}
    </RootContainer>
  );
};

export default ProductsList;
```

This is the getProducts() function that fetch data from another port.

```
const getProducts = async () => {
  let API_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/api/Products';

  const response: any = await fetch(API_URL);
  const data = await response.json();

  return data;
};
export default getProducts;
```

Comment: The code you wrote here looks pretty solid. Could you perhaps give a little more context by including getProducts, Product, & ProductItem? My guess is that products isn't getting passed through the props resulting in it being empty or undefined which would coincidently not return any ProductItems.

Comment: Also making a sandbox of it would help out immensely

Comment: you are receiving products as a prop. Why are yo calling `getProducts()` from the useEffect in this component ? Anyway you can console.log(products) just before the return statement and see what it contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue may be that you are retrieving the products but not actually doing anything with them - therefore the "products" check you perform before iterating will return false.

Try using a state variable:

```js
const ProductsList = () => {

  const [products, setProducts] = useState<product[]>();

  useEffect(() => {
    getProducts().then((result) => setProducts(result);
  }, []);

  return (
    <RootContainer>
      <h2>test</h2>
      {products &&
        products.map((product) => {
          return <ProductItem key={product.id} product={product} />;
        })}
    </RootContainer>
  );
};
```

The principal here is that when the getProducts() method returns it will update the state variable with a list of products. This change in state will cause the component to refresh and the products.map will be reached.

Comment: D sounds a lot promising your explaination. However, i get this error when I pass the getProducts().  Argument of type 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Product[]>'.
  Type 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to type '(prevState: Product[]) => Product[]'.
    Type 'Promise<any>' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: Product[]): Product[]'.ts(2345)
products-list.tsx(20, 17): Did you forget to use 'await'?

Comment: Sounds like your getProducts() is an async method (axios call?). Without seeing your code you should be able to do something like getProducts().then((result) => setProducts(result));

Comment: I have updated my question with the getProducts() code.

Answer (score 2):

You are fetching the products on the `useEffect` hook but are not storing them as a state value. Try using `useState` to achieve that, and try tweaking your rendering logic.

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
//...

interface Props {
  products: Product[] | [];
}

const ProductsList = (props: Props) => {

  const [products, setProducts] = useState<Product[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const _products = getProducts();
    console.log('fetched data',_products);
    setProducts(_products);
  }, []);

  return (
    <RootContainer>
      <h2>test</h2>
      {products &&
        products.map((product) => {
          return <ProductItem key={product.id} product={product} />;
        })}
    </RootContainer>
  );
};

export default ProductsList;
```

If you still don't see anything, try modifying your rendering logic like so:

```
<RootContainer>
    <h2>test</h2>
    {products && products.map((product) => 
        (<ProductItem key={product.id} product={product} />)
    )}
</RootContainer>
```

Since you are using TypeScript, conditional rendering needs to be handled a bit differently than from JS. So in your check for `products &&` try this:

```
<RootContainer>
    <h2>test</h2>
    {products ? products.map((product) => (
        <ProductItem key={product.id} product={product} />)
        : null
     )}
</RootContainer>
```

Now, depending on the props you've defined for the RootContainer component, passing a null as a `child` might not be allowed. If that's the case, try changing the `null` to `<></>` to pass a React Fragment instead

Comment: I am getting an error when i pass getProducts().      {products &&
        products.map((product) => {
          return <ProductItem key={product.id} product={product} />;
        })}

Comment: appreciate a lot the explainations. With the help of both answers combined , finally it works now. .